# json_decode showing no data

Tags: php, json

I'm using below logic to store data in JSON format in MySQL using PHP.

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value[1] == "page_keywords")
            $store .= json_encode(array($value[1] => $value[2]));
        else
            $store .= json_encode(array($value[1] => trim($value[2])));
    }

session_start();
$date = new Date();
$modified = $date->getDate();

$query = ' UPDATE pages SET last_updated_user_author_id = "'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'", data = "'.htmlentities($store, ENT_QUOTES).'", modified = "'.$modified.'" WHERE id = "'.$pageID.'" ';
```

Then while decoding the data i'm using below logic:

```
$query = ' SELECT data FROM pages WHERE id = "'.$_POST['pageID'].'" ';
$connection = $this->establish_connection();
$data = $connection->query($query);
$connection->close();
if($data->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $data->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $var = html_entity_decode($row['data']);
                echo json_decode($var);
            }
    }
```

While json_decode it shows no data in response, when i did var_dump it shows null, but if i did not do json_decode and only used html_entity_decode() i get below output

```
{"page_base_url":"http://www.myblog.com/about/contact/"}{"page_url_revision":"http://www.myblog.com/about/contact/"}{"page_url_alternate":"http://www.myblog.com/about/contact/"}{"page_url_shortlink":"http://www.myblog.com/about/contact/"}{"page_url_canonical":"http://www.myblog.com/about/contact/"}{"page_title":"Example | Contact"}{"page_name":"Example Contact"}{"page_type":"WebSite"}{"page_meta_description":"Want to get in touch with us? You're on the correct page, you can get in touch with us by filling the form below. We will get in touch with you with 24 hours."}{"page_keywords":["example","contact","support","help","getintouch","feedback","bug","updates"]}
```

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong, could anybody help me out here?

I want to give an eccho in json_encode format as a response to ajax call. i use below logic to do so

```
echo json_encode(
                array(
                        "type" => "error",
                        "status" => "Error While Retrieving Data!",
                        "message" => $error
                     )
            );
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can concatenate JSON-encoded objects, I think you need to build it as an array, and then JSON-encode it at the end of the loop.

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: droopsnot is right - the string you've shown is not valid JSON. If you wanted to store a list of objects like that in JSON format, they need to be within an array, and separated by commas. Otherwise they are just unrelated individual objects and cannot be decoded as a single block of JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
$store = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value[1] == "page_keywords")
            $store[] = array($value[1] => $value[2]);
        else
            $store[] = array($value[1] => trim($value[2]));
    }

$save = json_encode($store);
```

or even (if your $value[1] is always unique within the loop)

```
$store = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value[1] == "page_keywords")
            $store[$value[1]] = $value[2];
        else
            $store[$value[1]] = trim($value[2]);
    }

$save = json_encode($store);
```

then use $save to store in your table. I'm not 100% on that, though.

Comment: htmlentities() ? should i not use that?

Comment: I don't know, what happens when you try it? If you use prepared statements, I don't think there's a need for it.

Comment: if there are any ' or double quotes it stores it appropriately `htmlentities($store, ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: OK, well use that then, or use a prepared statement which will handle quotes for you.

Comment: how to use the prepared statement

Comment: For prepared statements look at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared - I don't know what makes a question valid or invalid here.

Answer (score 1):

The string you've shown is not valid JSON. If you wanted to store a list of objects like that in JSON format, they need to be within an array, and separated by commas. Otherwise they are just unrelated individual objects and cannot be decoded as a single block of JSON.

Therefore you need to build an array in PHP and then encode the whole thing at the end. Something like this:

```
$storedata = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
{
    if($value[1] == "page_keywords")
        $storedata[] = array($value[1] => $value[2]);
    else
        $storedata[] = array($value[1] => trim($value[2]));
}

$jsondata = json_encode($storedata);
```

And then use `$jsondata` in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your "saving" to the database. You encode every key-value-pair in an own json-string and concat those json-strings.

Your snippet

```php
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
{
    if($value[1] == "page_keywords")
        $store .= json_encode(array($value[1] => $value[2]));
    else
        $store .= json_encode(array($value[1] => trim($value[2])));
}
```

Yields `$store = "{key1:value1}{key2:value3}{key3:value3}"`. Note all the brackets, you have 3 distinct json-objects with a single key-value pair in your string, instead of one json-object with 3 key-value-pairs.

However, I assume you want a single json-object with the key-value-pairs as result like the folling?

```php
$store = "{
    key1:value1,
    key2:value2,
    key3:value3
}";
```

If so, you need to build your array differently:

```php
$store = array();
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
{
    if($value[1] == "page_keywords")
        $store[$value[1]] = $value[2];
    else
        $store[$value[1]] = trim($value[2]);
}
```

And please, for the safety of everyone, your code is vulnerable of sql-injections. Please fix that, too.

Comment: How to decode the data then? for sending like json_encode to the ajax request again

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav well, just do your `$save = json_encode($store);` again..?